# Sorting dynamically generated html table in modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have searched SO for a similar problem to mine but I can't find anything that would work. I have tried a number of different methods with 0 luck.

I have a modal popup window which I am calling by

```
<span><button id="products_button" class="btn dt_buttons ajax_forms" data-keyid="" data-source="store_products_list_popup.php" data-target="popup" data-element=""><i class="fa fa-list fa-md"></i><span>&nbsp; View Products </span></button>
```

In that file I have a table with header rows

```
<table id="tbl_store_product_sizes" class="table table-fixed table-striped table-bordered datalist" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>

            <tr >
                 <th> No. </th>
                 <th> Product Name  </th>
                 <th> Department Name </th>
                 <th> Unit Cost </th>
                 <th> Quantity Counted </th>
                 <th> Total Cost </th>

             </tr>


    </thead>
```

and  generated from MySQL query results

```
echo "<tr>";                    
                    echo "<td style='color:red' > $row_counter </td>";
                    echo "<td style='color:red; width:200px;' class='left_align' > $lstr_product_name </td>";
                    echo "<td style='color:red'> $lstr_department_name </td>";
                    echo "<td style='color:red' > <input type='text' name='unit_cost' class='form-control unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='$lint_unit_cost' /> <input name='product_id' class='form-control product_id' value='$lint_product_id' type='hidden'/> </td>";
                    echo "<td style='color:red' > <input type='text' tabindex='-1' readonly name='quantity_counted' class='form-control editable_control number_format unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='$lint_quantity_counted' />  </td>";
                    echo "<td style='color:red' > <input type='text' tabindex='-1' readonly name='total_cost' class='form-control editable_control number_format unit_cost' style='width:50px;' value='$lint_total_cost' />  </td>";


                    echo "</tr>";
```

I am trying to make this table sortable by being able to click on the header rows. I have tried the jQuery tablesorter plugin but it doesn't seem to be giving me expected results. The file from which I am calling the modal is called home_stocktake_locations.php. In that file I have added

```
    $(function(){
  $("#tbl_store_product_sizes").tablesorter();
});
```

Which didn't work at all. I have also tried to do it by the class name

```
$(function(){
  $(".table").tablesorter();
});
```

Now this works for all tables in home_stocktake_locations.php and I am able to sort them, but it doesn't affect the modal generated by store_products_list_popup.php. I have also tried to add the same function in the popup file but no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to sort tables in a modal or do I need to take a different approach?

Comment: The modal tables are only being built when they're viewed, I'm guessing.  That means that they probably don't exist when you first execute `.tablesorter()`.  Just call it again as you show the modal, after you populate the tables.

Comment: If you are getting no results at all it is likely that the jQuery is running before the table is populated. To do a little debugging, you could try to run `$("#tbl_store_product_sizes").tablesorter();` in the console after the data in the table is populated. It should either give you the result you are looking for which would confirm the data is being populated after the function runs OR it should throw an error. Also checking the console for errors in general is a good way to figure out what your issues are if you are not getting an expected outcome.

Comment: @Matthew good advice in the first part, but rather unlikely it will throw error. jQuery fails quietly when no selector match found

Comment: @Matthew when I ran that in console after modal opened then it worked fine and sorted the information. So it is the fact that the jQuery is called before table is populated. In this case, where and when is the proper way of calling $("#tbl_store_product_sizes").tablesorter();?

Comment: @charlietfl yes! Thank you for that clarification. After I submitted that I saw my mistake in not including that in there.

Comment: Don't mind my previous question - got it! :) Thanks for your advice, much easier to resolve than I thought...

Comment: Great! glad we could help :)

Comment: Another question, it doesn't seem like the sort is working with <input type ='text'>, is there a way around it so that all columns are sortable?

Comment: Default tablesorter sort functions are based on text. You will have to extend the sort function for that column with your own that retrieves the input value. See examples in docs